# ListDir which contains only pdf files

Tags: ionic4

I need a help regarding Ionic-4 code.I want to list the directories which contains only PDF files in it using lisDir method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code, this should work in Android, I didn't get time to test this but should work;

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform,
          private filePath: FilePath, private file: File) {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.file.listDir(file.externalDataDirectory, '').then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      for (const fl of result) {
        if (fl.isDirectory == true && fl.name != '.' && fl.name != '..') {
          // Code if its a folder
          } else if (fl.isFile == true) {
            const fName = fl.name; // File name
            const path = fl.fullPath; // File path
            if(fName.toLowerCase().endsWith('.pdf')) {
              // do Something
            }

          }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me it using LisDir method

Comment: listDir = (path, dirName) => { this.fileNavigator .listDir(path, dirName) .then(entries => { this.items = entries; }) .catch(this.handleError); }